# CancellationToken not Canceled in Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, task

I have a problem with Tas.WaitAll.

```
var t = new List<Task>() {
        Task.Run(() => {
           while (! this.cancToken.Token.IsCancellationRequested) { // Here Cancellation Request is always false :(
                 Thread.Sleep(100);
              };

        }, this.cancToken.Token )

     };
     // this.cancToken is CancellationTokenSource
     var token = this.cancToken.Token;
     await Task.Run(() => Task.WaitAll(t.ToArray(), 1000, token));
```

Why Task.WaitAll don't cancel the CancellationToken ?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to wrap blocking `WaitAll` call into `Task.Run` and use `Thread.Sleep(100);` inside?

Comment: Where are you cancelling? Also, why use blocking operations in async code rather than using `WhenAll` and `Task.Delay`?

Comment: I don't see  `TaskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` call in your code anywhere. You should probably add this statement to example if you removed it. Otherwise, you should call it in order to move token to canceled state.

Comment: This is test Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`Cancel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=netcore-3.1) on `this.cancToken` (assuming it is `CancellationTokenSource`) so it will cancel token:

```
await Task.Run(() => Task.WaitAll(t.ToArray(), 1000, token)); 
this.cancToken.Cancel();
```

[`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___System_Int32_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) accepts as a parameter a cancellation token to observe while waiting for the tasks to complete and will throw `OperationCanceledException` if it was canceled. Also there is no `Cancel` method on token itself (which is passed to `Task.WaitAll`).

Comment: Reading the documentation I thought that when the waitAll ran out of the set time it automatically canceled the CancellationToken. I misunderstood. Thank you! :)